# Directory path of a GitHub repository

Tags: php, github, path, directory

In my PHP code I'm finding the **total number of files** (in my case, images) in the directory. I'm hosting these images on a **subfolder in my GitHub repo**. I don't think I'm using the correct ***$dir path***.

***PHP code:***

```
<?php

        $dir        = "/username/repoName/tree/master/images";
        $fi         = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
        $fileCount  = iterator_count($fi);

        echo $fileCount;

    ?>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message
>
> > 'FilesystemIterator::__construct(/releafgroup/dashboard/tree/master/images>)
> >     [filesystemiterator.--construct]: failed to open dir: **No such file or directory'** in
> >     ***full file path***

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't have that working this way.

You are passing an absolute dirPath to the FilesystemIterator so it tells you a path like this does not exist in your filesystem.

What I could imagine would be defining path to the root directory of your application, sth like the following:

```
$appPath = '/var/www/myApp';
```

and then

```
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($appPath . '/vendor/username/repoName/tree/master/images', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
```

Comment: Ok, what would *var, www and myApp* be?

Comment: The path to the directory of your project. In case it's just a single file then the path to the directory where the file is located.

Comment: If you would like your github package to display that (that means you don't know what the project path would be if someone included your package) then have a look at \_\_DIR\_\_ or \_\_FILE\_\_ to find a relation between the file being executed and the location of your images directory you want to iterate through.

Comment: I'm getting: *Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'FilesystemIterator::__construct(/home/content//html/directory_etc/name/repo/tree/master/images) [<a href='filesystemiterator.--construct'>filesystemiterator.--construct</a>]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory'*

Comment: Replace the "name" with your github username and the "repo" with your repository name.